# How to check table database in joomla 2.5 with php

Tags: php, joomla

I have been making a function to get specific value of joomla 2.5 database. But, now I meet a problem again. In here, I was made new three tables in joomla, let say

1. joomlatest_name1_year1
2. joomlatest_name1_year2

The problem is, how to know the table is really exist in joomla database with php? thanks for advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Joomla! framework provides a method to retrieve the names of existing tables.

```
$tables = JFactory::getDbo()->getTableList();
print_r($tables);
```

A simple check with `in_array()` is able to tell you, if the expected table is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('*'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__name1_year1'));
$db->setQuery($query);

if($query){
     echo "Table Exists";
}
else {
     echo "Table doesn't exist";
}
```

I haven't tested this but hope it helps.

Comment: Lodder, this doesn't work in Joomla 3, I think, or at least when running the extension installation script.php, because it produces an error and cancels the installation.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos - I've updated my answer as it was written a long time ago. I will give it a proper test later on tonight

Comment: I have tried to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`" during installation, to check if it exists and it returns as an unsuccessful installation.